# How can I reference keys in an object (not values) to implement keyboard support for a calculator?

Tags: javascript, object, keyboard, calculator, key-value

I'm trying to add keyboard support to my calculator so you can just press keys instead of clicking on the screen. This looked like a good chance to practice using objects, but I'm obviously doing something wrong here. Can you give me a hint?

```js
let keyboard = {
  48: zeroFunc,
  49: oneFunc,
  50: twoFunc,
  51: threeFunc,
  52: fourFunc,
  53: fiveFunc,
  54: sixFunc,
  55: sevenFunc,
  56: eightFunc,
  57: nineFunc
};
```

I've tried something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === keyboard.key) {
        keyboard[action]
    }
}
```

and this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
Object.keys(keyboard).forEach(key, index) => {
    if (e.keyCode === key) {
      keyboard[index]
    }
  }
};
```

I could just make an if statement for each keycode, but I suspect there's a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Well since you already have an object mapping key-codes to functions, you could simply call them like so:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (keyboard[e.keyCode] != undefined) {
         keyboard[e.keyCode](e); //<--  you need to call the function, once you get it...
    }
};
```

Or perhaps even,

```
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
         keyboard[e.keyCode] ? keyboard[e.keyCode](e) : null; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    const action = keyboard[e.keyCode];
    if (action) action();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just one if statement

```
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (keyboard[e.keyCode])
        keyboard[e.keyCode]();
}
```

If `e.keyCode` is not one of the values in the object keyboard, `keyboard[e.keyCode]` will return `undefined` and the inside code will not run.

You also need to add parentheses after the function to actually call it

Comment: this actually didn't work for me! It's kind of like haxor's answer and I tried to simplify his by getting rid of the const but for some reason it doesn't work that way

Comment: Perhaps try `document.onkeydown = checkKeyPressed` instead of `document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);`